# Adding Title to Histogram in a Function

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram

I made a simple function to automatically plot all variables in a dataframe. Below is the code,

```
V1 <- rnorm(50)
V2 <- rnorm(50)
all.data <- data.frame(V1, V2)
My_function <- function(x)
for(i in x) {
        hist(i)
}
My_function(all.data)
```

The problem is that the title of each histograms is always "Histogram of i"  . This can be really confusing if I make fifty histograms with this function. 
I need to know how to fix this so that each histogram has the title of column it comes from in the dataframe. In other words, the first histogram should have the title "Histogram of V1" and the second should have the title "Histogram of V2".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like the following?

```
V1 <- rnorm(50)
V2 <- rnorm(50)
all.data <- data.frame(V1, V2)
My_function <- function(x)
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    hist(x[,i], main = paste("Histogram of",colnames(x)[i]))
  }
My_function(all.data)
```

Note that `i` now represents the column number, rather than the values in the column itself.